# Emacs lisp key binding in shell mode not working

Tags: emacs

I have my emacs editor setup to run a shell when I press `Ctrl-z`.  When inside of a shell buffer, I use `Ctrl-z` to clear the buffer by running the `erase-buffer` function.  The code is being evaluated (when I `Ctrl-h v` and describe the `shell-mode-map` I can see that `C-z` is bound to `clear-shell-buffer` in shell mode.  When I run the `clear-shell-buffer` with `M-x` the message says:

> You can run the command `clear-shell-buffer` with <C-z>

However, when I type `Ctrl-z` in the shell it does not run the function or give any messages at all.  Any idea why?

```
(defun clear-shell-buffer ()
  "Clear the contents of the current buffer"
  (interactive)
  (erase-buffer)
  ;;  (insert "/usr/games/fortune -a")
  (comint-send-input)
  )

(put 'erase-buffer 'disabled nil)
(eval-after-load 'shell
  '(define-key shell-mode-map [(\C-z)] 'clear-shell-buffer))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of the key binding being incorrect. You can verify this by doing `C-h k C-z` when in shell mode.

Instead of `[(\C-z)]`, use one of these options:

- `[(?\C-z)]`
- `[(control ?z)]`
- `(kbd "C-z")`

which will correctly set the key binding, and let you call the correct function with `C-z`

You can see a little bit of what's happening if you evaluate just the those statements. Here's the output I get for each

```
(define-key shell-mode-map [(\C-z)] 'clear-shell-buffer)
;;Output: (define-key shell-mode-map [(C-z)] (quote clear-shell-buffer))

(define-key shell-mode-map [(?\C-z)] 'clear-shell-buffer)
;;Output: (define-key shell-mode-map [(26)] (quote clear-shell-buffer))
```

You can see that the types differ for the key binding. Right now, you're passing a symbol, when you want to be passing a character code.